# React Redux: undefined reducer action

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, reduce, redux-reducers

I made increment & decrement counter buttons, I'm using redux to trigger actions of increment and decrement but Im getting "***Counter.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addition')***" error by clicking the button.

Here is the code:-

**store.js**

```
const counterSlice = createSlice({
    name: "counter",
    initialState: {
        countNumber: 0,
        countToggle: true,
    },
    reducers: {
        addition(state) {
            state.countNumber++;
        },
        subtraction(state) {
            state.countReducer--;
        },          
    },
});
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: counterSlice.reducer,
})

export const storeAction = store.actions;

export default store;
```

**Counter.js**

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { storeAction } from "../redux-store/store";

const counter = useSelector((state) => state.countNumber);
    
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const addHandler = () => {
    dispatch(storeAction.addition());
};

//jsx
<div className={classes.value}>{counter}</div>
<button onClick={addHandler}>addition</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be?

```
export const storeAction = counterSlice.actions
```

Comment: oh yeah, thanks for your help, but now I can't trigger other action, eg-subtraction() action ...


const subtractHandler = () => {
  dispatch(storeAction.subtraction());
 };

Comment: I don't see why would this happen if `addition` works.

Comment: write state.countNumber-- instead of  state.countReducer--